# How to mainpulate file after reading it in Javascript/Vue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2, synchronous

I have a method that gets the contents of the file and stores it into a string. My `this.parseText` is a global variable:

```
`   openFile(event) {
        const inputFile = event.target.files[0];
        const readerObject = new FileReader();
        let fileText = 'Empty';
        readerObject.onload = function () {
          fileText = readerObject.result;
          this.parseText = fileText;
          console.log(fileText);
        };
        readerObject.readAsText(inputFile);
        return this.parseText;
},
```

`

I also have a button that when the user clicks on it, it should manipulate the string. The HTML is:
`<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".csv" @change="openFile"/>      <button v-on:click="testButton">Test me!</button>`
 I have a function called:

`testButton() {
   console.log(this.parseText);
 },`

However when I console this, it does not print the content of the file. This is due to the openFile being asynchronous. How can I use javascript (no jQuery) to wait for `this.parseText` to contain the necessary String in order to manipulate it in my `testButton()` function?

Comment: i dont know this is a good aproach, but what you can do is, simply disable the button and enable only after the parseText has some value.

Comment: That's also a good idea. I finally solved this problem by putting the asynchronous function inside the button function, so that it only reads the file after the button has been clicked.